# jstree initial node id

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

**How can I specify the first ID to be sent in the ajax call on jstree?**

This is my code copied from the demo files with the url set to my ajax call:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#treeview').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': {
        "url": "tree.asp",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (node) {
          return { "id": node.id };
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

This is the ajax url jstree sent when the page is loaded;

```
tree.asp?id=%23
```

Where it is getting the "**%23**" from I have no idea.  I want to specify this "**id**" number on the very first load.

Once the initial tree is loaded clicking on the child node works fine.  The proper ID as provided in the json data returned is then used to load the child data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is an internal jstree value, used for the tree root ID. To replace it in your initial AJAX call use this:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#treeview').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': {
        "url": "tree.asp",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (node) {
          return { "id": node.id === "#" ? "YOUR_ID" : node.id };
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Replace `"YOUR_ID"` with what you need, of course - the only change is in that line.

Comment: Thanks!  That solved it.  I see you are the author of jsTree.  So far its doing a great job for my project right out of the box.